# Orbital Resonance & Tidal Locking

Tags: orbital-mechanics

I'm building a habitable world tidally locked to a red dwarf star. In order to affect a tide and other weather patterns I was going to have another planet closer to the star that has an orbital resonance with the world I am building.

Can a tidally locked planet be affected by orbital resonance and stay tidally locked?

Answer (score 4):

> Can a tidally locked planet be affected by orbital resonance and stay tidally locked?

Yes, it is possible.

The moons orbiting around the giant planets in our solar system have both tidal locking and orbital resonance.

I.e. Jupiter [Galilean moons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_moons) have orbital resonances 1:2:4 and are also tidally locked.